# Ghidra resolving ordinals (WS2_32.DLL)

Tags: ghidra

I think I have done this in the past but I cannot remember anymore.

What are the steps to make Ghidra in Linux recognise the import names instead of using the Ordinals?

(They are recognised automatically in Windows)

[image: Ghidra Symbol Tree]